# How to enter values from dataframe directly into sweave latex pdf processing

Tags: r, latex, sweave

I have the following code in Rstudio-Sweave that produces a simple table:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
5  & 6  & 11 & 22 & 33 & 44 & 55 & 55 & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{name1} & 66 & 777 & 888 \\ \hline
v1 & v2 & v3 & v4 & v5 & v6 & v7 & v8 & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{name2} & v9 & v10 & v11 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

How do i edit the code so that value '5', '6', 'v1'-'v11', etc take values directly from a data.frame that i have already created. For example if i have dataframe named 'DATAFRAME' is it possible to do something like this (it doesn't work) but surely there is something simple like this that can be done?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
DATAFRAME[1,1]  & 6  & 11 & 22 & 33 & 44 & 55 & 55 & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{name1} & 66 & 777 & 888 \\ \hline
v1 & v2 & v3 & DATAFRAME[4,4] & v5 & v6 & v7 & v8 & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{DATAFRAME[4,5]} & v9 & v10 & v11 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

Where i've replaced the values within the table with values taken dynamically from the dataframe - can this be done?

Comment: I think knitr::kable() will give you what you want. It outputs a markdown formatted table

Comment: The `xtable` package can also get this done and has a number of formatting options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `\Sexpr{DATAFRAME[1,1]}`, `\Sexpr{DATAFRAME[4,4]}`, etc. That will pull the values you specify from the dataframe. However, if you are trying to make a whole table at once, definitely look into the options in `knitr` and `xtable` mentioned by Kristofersen and Imo. Much easier than making repeated `\Sexpr{}` calls.

Edit:
Try the following code to see if this works on your machine. I just set it to use a random data set for DATAFRAME.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<data, echo = FALSE>>=
set.seed(100)
DATAFRAME <- data.frame(round(rnorm(n = 10),2),
                        round(rnorm(n = 10),2),
                        round(rnorm(n = 10),2),
                        round(rnorm(n = 10),2),
                        round(rnorm(n = 10),2))
@

\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\Sexpr{DATAFRAME[1,1]}  & 6  & 11 & 22 & 33 & 44 & 55 & 55 & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{name1} & 66 & 777 & 888 \\ \hline
v1 & v2 & v3 & \Sexpr{DATAFRAME[4,4]} & v5 & v6 & v7 & v8 & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{\Sexpr{DATAFRAME[4,5]}} & v9 & v10 & v11 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Says error: "Error: at temp.Rnw:12, object 'DATAFRAME' not found"? During the compile phase

Comment: Is your data frame actually named DATAFRAME? Or is that just what you were using as an example in your question? Make sure it matches the name of your data frame if it is different from DATAFRAME.

Comment: I just edited my answer with a small example. Give it a shot and see if it works. If not, there might be some other problems.

Comment: Yes - that works, great thanks. Not sure what the problem was before - possibly that i had created the dataframe separately in a different code script, not sure.